# Split a source into multiple zip files using ANT

Tags: ant, split, zip

I want to ask if the following is possible with ANT scripting, hopefully not using any external libraries.  I have the current script.

```
<project default="zip" name="antexample">
  <target name="zip">
    <tstamp/>
    <zip destfile="dest/new.zip" basedir="src" excludes="*.properties"/>
    <echo file="metadata.properties"/>
    <copy todir="dest">
      <fileset dir=".">
        <include name="*.properties"/>
      </fileset>
    </copy>
  </target>
</project>
```

What I hope to be able to do is split the src directory into more than one zip dependent on size.  So every time a zip file reaches the limit of 1mb it starts to create a new zip to the limit of 1mb and so on until all of the data is zipped.

Hopefully someone can help.  Many thanks in advance.

Comment: The following link suggests using a program like jSplit to break your large zip up into smaller files. Problem is each smaller file won't be a valid standalone zip. Very difficult to do this and yet be exactly 1mb in size. http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/ant-user/200510.mbox/%3C007101c5d401$dd339c10$0d02a8c0@athlon%3E